# Deleting a Previously sent Notification in a Django Project

Tags: python, django

I have an issue with deleting notifications that was previously sent when a user liked a post.

First I have a Like button related to a post which is working fine.

***My issue*** is I have a Post model and a Like Model (many to many relation) and I have created signal from notification model where when a user clicks to like on a post a signal is sent and a notification is created, ***but*** I am struggling with the logic that if the same user `Unlike` the post (clicking the like button for the second time), I want a signal to be sent to delete the created notification from the very same user.

**So currently here is what is happening:**

1. A User clicks the Like button. The *value* of the Like button is `Like`
2. Notification sent to the Author of the Post
3. The same user clicks the Like button again. The *value* of the Like button is `Unike`
4. Nothing happens

**Required outcome:**

4. The previously sent notification to the Author that a post was liked to be deleted

***What I want is the previously sent notification to be deleted when the post is unliked***

*Here is my Models.py related to the Post Model:*

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author')
    num_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='No. of Likes')
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='liked', blank=True)
```

*Here is the views.py:*

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "blog/post_detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data()
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        total_likes = post.total_likes()
        liked = False
        if post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True

        post_likes = post.likes.all()
        context["liked"] = liked
        context["post_likes"] = post_likes

        return context
```

*Like Models.py:*

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(choices=LIKE_CHOICES, default='Like', max_length=8)

    def user_liked_post(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        like = instance
        if like.value=='Like':
            post = like.post
            sender = like.user
            notify = Notification(post=post, sender=sender, user=post.author, notification_type=1)
            notify.save()

    def user_unlike_post(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        like = instance
        post = like.post
        sender = like.user
        notify = Notification.objects.filter(post=post, sender=sender, user=post.author, notification_type=1)
        notify.delete()

post_save.connect(Like.user_liked_post, sender=Like)
post_delete.connect(Like.user_unlike_post, sender=Like)
```

*Here is the like views.py:*

```
def LikeView(request):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('id'))
    liked = False
    current_likes = post.num_likes
    user = request.user
    if post.author.id == request.user.id:
        messages.warning(request, 'You can not like you own Post')

    else:

        like, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(user=user, post=post)
        sender = like.user
        if not created:
            if like.value == 'Like':
                like.value = 'Unlike'
                like.user_unliked_post(sender=sender, post=post) <------- My trial
            else:
                like.value = 'Like'
        like.save()

    context = {
        'total_likes': post.total_likes,
        'liked': liked,
        'post': post,
    }
    if request.is_ajax:
        html = render_to_string('blog/like_section.html', context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

I have tried to add `user_unlike_post`in the `LikeView` but I am getting an error `AttributeError: 'Like' object has no attribute 'user_unliked_post'`

I am not sure if it was the right thing to try to delete the previous signal from the `LikeView`.

**My question how can I delete the previous notification sent when a user unlike the post?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function `delete_notification` like following.

```
def delete_notification(sender, post):
    notify = Notification.objects.filter(post=post, sender=sender, user=post.author, notification_type=1)
    notify.delete()
```

And call the function in `LikeView`.

```
def LikeView(request):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('id'))
    liked = False
    current_likes = post.num_likes
    user = request.user
    if post.author.id == request.user.id:
        messages.warning(request, 'You can not like you own Post')

    else:

        like, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(user=user, post=post)
        sender = like.user
        if not created:
            if like.value == 'Like':
                like.value = 'Unlike'

                delete_notification(sender, post)

            else:
                like.value = 'Like'
        like.save()

    context = {
        'total_likes': post.total_likes,
        'liked': liked,
        'post': post,
    }
    if request.is_ajax:
        html = render_to_string('blog/like_section.html', context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

Hope that will work.

Also note that both the `user_liked_post` and `user_unlike_post` methods are missing `self` argument in your `Like` model.

Comment: I added the delete_notification function and recalled it in the view.py but I am getting TypeError: delete_notification() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: How 3 arguments are given to delete_notification function? Did you add new arguments when calling? Where do you put delete_notification function in your code?

Comment: after the if condition `like.delete_notification(sender, post)`

Comment: Then make the signature to this `def delete_notification(self, sender, post):` Add the `self` argument.